# How to make asp-route-{value} tag helper take value from variable?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I would like to achieve the thing below:

```
@{ 
    var myParam = "foo";
    var myValue = 1;
}
<a asp-controller = "mycontroller" asp-action = "myaction" asp-route-@(myParam) = "@myValue">doit</a>
```

And it should generate this (according to a default route template):

```
<a href="http://hostname/mycontroller/myaction/foo=1">doit</a>
```

But this part does not work:

```
asp-route-@(myParam)
```

It is possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, asp-all-route-data does it.

```
@{
    var myParam = "foo";
    var myValue = 1;
    var parms = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { myParam, myValue.ToString() }
    };
}
<a asp-controller="mycontroller" asp-action="myaction" asp-all-route-data="parms">doit</a>
```